# Implementacion de Bulk Insert SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv

Estoy usando SQL Server 2017 Express y estoy usando un procedimiento almacenado para cargar los datos de un `CSV` que genera un programa X.

Esta es una muestra del `CSV`.

```
 indice;hora;puerta;num;nombre;departamento;departamento;id usuario;estado;detalle
"0001";"05:51:56";"Parqueadero";"0046";"Rafael Iglesia";"ADMINISTRATIVOS";"Dep2_00";"922269778";"(M11)Acceso Normal";"04756:22242"
```

No se si se aprecia bien, pero la primera línea es el encabezado, y esto no interesa, así que en el `bulk insert` se parametrizó que coja desde la segunda fila.
El problema radica en un error en un campo de datos, ¿Que es el último campo, cosa rara porque debería de insertar de forma normal no?

Aquí la parte de como se está implementa el comando, y la tabla de destino.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMPORAL_IV](
[id_temp_dia] int NULL,
[hora_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[puerta_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[id_tar_temp] int NULL,
[usuario_temp] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[desc_dep_temp] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[id_dep_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[doc_usu_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[mensaje_temp] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[num_tar_us_temp] [nvarchar](30) NULL) 

BULK INSERT TEMPORAL_IV from '\\X\X$\temp\datos.csv' with (fieldterminator=';',FIRSTROW='2');
```

Este es error:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 10 (num_tar_us_temp).
```

Comment: Mire la información del archivo csv, probablemente `id_temp_dia` o `id_tar_temp` tiene un valor que NO es `int`. ¿qué valores contiene `num_tar_us_temp` y es necesario que el campo sea de longitud 30?

Comment: El de  id_temp si es un error que debo de corregir, pero lo del ultimo valor me parece extraño que no de, ya que sin importar el tamaño, debería de cargar esos datos no?

Y aquí urgando en el código, si coloco que FIRSTROW= 2, entonces no carga el archivo, y aparece 0 rows affected.

Comment: Yerson, ¿qué tipo de datos tiene la columna `num_tar_us_temp`? - puede que tenga vacíos - si puede hacer el cargue sin la última columna y funciona, digo yo que es un problema de datos con los datos de esa columna - puede que esa columna tenga una coma de mas (o separador) que genere este error. Intente también abrir el csv en Excel para ver mejor la información del csv antes de exportar la información a la base de datos.